# Swift 3.0 NSArray valueForKey

Tags: swift, nsarray, swift3

In Swift 2.3 I've used this code, but after updating Swift to version 3.0 my code can't compile. Thank you!

```
var waterfallLibrary: NSArray = []
cell!.textLabel?.text = String(self.waterfallLibrary.valueForKey("songName").objectAtIndex(indexPath.row))
```

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: `value(forKey: "songName")`

Comment: `(waterfallLibrary.value(forKey: "songName") as! NSArray).object(at: indexPath.row)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My problem solved with this code

```
(waterfallLibrary.value(forKey: "songName") as! NSArray).object(at: indexPath.row)
```

Thank you Leo Dabus!

Comment: Lol. So the answer I gave then. Why duplicate my answer into your own answer?

Comment: Your original answer was wrong. `valueForKey(key: blah)`

Comment: BTW your answer still wrong. You are passing an Int instead of a String there after editing it.

Answer (score 1):

In swift 3.0 the first parameter name is required. So your code should be...

```
value(forKey: indexPath.row)
```

If you read the error message it will tell you this and it will even correct it for you.

If you want to convert all your code just use the built in xcode converter that will do all of this for you. Again, this will be offered when you open the project in Xcode 8.

Comment: I know, but I need additional use indexPath.row

Comment: @DmitriyGroschovskiy not sure why that is a problem? Just put `indexPath.row` where I put blah.